# Bootstrap col doesn't work with Full Page JS

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, fullpage.js

I want to use Fullpage JS together with Bootstrap. However when I make two elements with `col-lg-6` classes inside a full page section, they stack vertically and not horizontally on a large screen. Does anyone know how to fix this so my bootstrap columns are full width and stack horizontally next to each other like normally?

```html
<div class="container-fluid" id="fullpage">
<!-- Home -->
<div class="row section" id="home">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h1>Another test</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Who we are -->
<div class="row section" id="who-we-are">
    Test
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have included the bootstrap css. Adding the stylesheet solved your issue for me. Then, be aware that the two columns will only show up on large screens as defined by col-lg. I also tested it with the fullpage js plugin which was fine.

See the below code snippet for the stylesheet import and be aware that I changed col-lg-6 to col-6 so that the preview on the small viewport here on StackOverflow would show the columns.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid" id="fullpage">
<!-- Home -->
<div class="row section" id="home">
    <div class="col-6">
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <h1>Another test</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Who we are -->
<div class="row section" id="who-we-are">
    Test
</div>
</div>
```